# the intersection of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Is the following statement true?:

- Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring, $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of $R$,then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists m_n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I^{m_n}\bigcap J^{m_n} \subseteq (I\bigcap J)^n$.

It seems enough to prove it when $n=2$ since $I^{m_2\cdot m_2^\prime}\bigcap J^{m_2\cdot m_2^\prime}\subseteq (I^{m_2}\bigcap J^{m_2})^2 \subseteq ((I\bigcap J)^2)^2\subseteq (I\bigcap J)^3$, and it is similar afterward.

Comment: in the question, did you mean "such that $I^{m_n} \cap J^{m_n} \subseteq (I \cap J)^n$?

Comment: An example to illlustrate the nontriviality of this question: for $n \ge 2$, set $R_n := \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^n - y^n)$, $I = (x)$, $J = (y)$. Then $x^n = y^n \in (I^n \cap J^n) \setminus (I \cap J)^2$. In particular, there is no uniform choice of $m_2$ which is independent of $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct corollary of Artin-Rees theorem:

> ($\textbf{Artin-Rees}$) Suppose that R is a Noetherian commutative ring, $I\subset R$ an ideal. Let $N\subset M$ be finite $R-$module. There exists a constant $c>0$ such that $I^nM\bigcap N = I^{n-c}(I^cM\bigcap N)$ for all $n\geq c$.

Now, let $M=R,N=J$,then $\forall m\geq n+c,I^m \bigcap J^m \subset I^m\bigcap J^n = I^{m-c}(I^c\bigcap J^n)\subset I^n J^n \subset (I\bigcap J)^n$.